# Why is my query slow when replacing the column I join on?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, left-join

Hi this is more of a general question when I run the query below my query takes about 1.5hours to run, however when I switch from joining "ACC_ID" to "ULT_ID" then my query takes 5+ hours. I know without the source information it may be hard to diagnose, but I am wondering if there's something basic I'm missing.

The amount of unique values for "ACC_ID" and "ULT_ID" are around the same

Original Query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
  op."Acc_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, CASE WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND ac3."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN  'Match @ ALL Levels'
       WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL 
       THEN  'Match @ ACC_ID, Prod1 Levels'
       WHEN ac1."Acc_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'Match @ ACC_ID Level'
       ELSE 'No Match @ ACC_ID Level' END CF       
FROM Oppty op
LEFT JOIN Acc ac1 ON op."Acc_ID" = ac1."Acc_ID"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac2 ON op."Acc_ID" = ac2."Acc_ID"
                   AND ac2."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac3   ON op."Acc_ID" = ac3."Acc_ID"
                   AND ac3."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
                   AND ac3."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op" 
  ORDER BY op."Acc_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

Query which takes much longer

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
  op."ULT_ID"
, op."Oppty_ID"
, op."Prod1op"
, op."Prod2op"
, CASE WHEN ac1."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL AND ac3."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN  'Match @ ALL Levels'
       WHEN ac1."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL AND  ac2."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL 
       THEN  'Match @ ULT_ID, Prod1 Levels'
       WHEN ac1."ULT_ID" IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'Match @ ULT_ID Level'
       ELSE 'No Match @ ULT_ID Level' END CF       
FROM Oppty op
LEFT JOIN Acc ac1 ON op."ULT_ID" = ac1."ULT_ID"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac2 ON op."ULT_ID" = ac2."ULT_ID"
                   AND ac2."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
LEFT JOIN Acc ac3   ON op."ULT_ID" = ac3."ULT_ID"
                   AND ac3."Prod1acc" = op."Prod1op"
                   AND ac3."Prod2acc" = op."Prod2op" 
  ORDER BY op."ULT_ID", op."Prod1op"
```

Comment: Best guess without any other code or schema definition to go on is that one column is indexed properly and the other isn't.

Comment: Do you know how to index a column?

Comment: That's *one* possible reason, of many. You need to contact your DBA, and should probably generate explain plans of your queries to check the actual execution paths. That will help you understand exactly what the database is spending its time on. Your DBA can help with that analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on how the index is set up, but the distribution of the data is also an important indicator.
Perhaps it is the case below.
Case 1. The op.Acc_ID is indexed and op.ULT_ID is not indexed.
Case 2. op.Acc_ID has higher cardinality.

Comment: what is cardinality?

Comment: @Noobanalyst415 Cardinality is the size of a set.